# Prove the pseudo inverse is a discontinuous function of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> Prove that the pseudo inverse is a discontinuous function of a matrix. Hint: Compute the pseudoinverse of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

So as far as I understand, I need to show that if $f$ is function that takes a real $m\times n$ matrix and assigns to it its unique $n\times m$ pseudoinverse, then $f$ is discontinuous.

Here's my approach:

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $E=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

We get that the pseudo inverse of $(A+\epsilon E)$ is $(A+\epsilon E)^+=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^+=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\epsilon} & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Hence $(A+\epsilon E)\rightarrow A$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$, but $lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}(A+\epsilon E)^+$ does not exist. Would this imply that $f$ is discontinuous, since the limit of the $(A+\epsilon E)$ exists, but the limit of the pseudoinverse of $(A+\epsilon E)$ does not? Or have I misunderstood something? I'm not sure if I understand the concept of $f$ being discontinuous

*I denote the pseudoinverse of a matrix with $^+$

Comment: What is the pseudo-inverse of $A$?

Comment: You are missing something, because if it worked  your argument would show that the usual inverse is discontinuous. In particular, you need that the pseudo inverse of $A$ exists, in contrast to the case for square matrices, where the inverse just isn't defined for every matrix.

Comment: @LutzL I've not found the pseudo inverse of A. I've found the pseudo inverse of $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix}$ to be $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \frac{1}{\epsilon} & 0\end{matrix}$, and then looked at each of those limits as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$

Comment: @Aaron So I would need to show the Moore-Penrose properties hold, or how would one show that the pseudo-inverse exists?

Comment: Every matrix has a pseudo-inverse, for$A$ you get $A^+=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$. So that the function is not simply undefined at the pole but has a valid value. In general, on the sets of constant rank, the pseudo-inverse is continuous, between the sets are infinite jumps.

Comment: @LutzL Can you provide some references that I can look into details on your comments; On the sets of constant rank, the pseudo-inverse is continuous.

Comment: @induction601 : Construct the pseudo-inverse via SVD, the continuity is inherited from the continuity of the SVD, and the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @LutzL The main difficulty I have is that for two matrices $A$ and $B$, they do not share the common singular vectors, i.e., $U_A \ne U_B$ and $V_A \ne V_B$. If they are, the continuity readily follows. But not sure how to deal with different singular vectors of $A$ and $B$... Any further suggestions would be very appreciated.

Comment: @LutzL (Editted comments) Thanks for your comment. I think I am struggling with the continuity of SVD. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \to \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}\times \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is the SVD function. In order to argue that $f$ is continuous, i.e., the continuity of SVD, we need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $B$ satisfying $\|A-B\|_F < \delta$, $\sqrt{\|U_A-U_B\|_F^2 + \|\Sigma_A-\Sigma_B\|_F^2 + \|V_A-V_B \|_F^2} \le \epsilon$. But not sure how it works.

Comment: @LutzL I opened a post on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389899. So I can potentially credit you.

Comment: It would have to be the "large" SVD, and only one of the possible SVD of $B$ has to be close to the given one of $A$, not all of them. The aim is to construct the pseudo-inverse and show their closeness, this is independent of the SVD chosen.