# Continuity of Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, continuity, singular-values

I am trying to show that the singular value decomposition is continuous.
For a matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$, let $s = \min\{m,n\} =n$, i.e, $(m \ge n)$.
Let $A = U_A\Sigma_A V_A^T$ be a SVD of $A$ and it is unique up to a sign change of both columns of $U_A$ and $V_A$.

First, let us choose any fixed $U_A$ and $V_A$.
Let $(U_A^{(1)},V_A^{(1)}) = (U_A,V_A)$.
Then, let us define $f_k:\mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that 
$$
f_{k}(A) = [U_A^{(k)},\Sigma_A,V_A^{(k)}],
$$
where $A = U_A^{(k)}\Sigma_A(V_A^{(k)})^T$ is a singular value decomposition of $A$ and $(U_A^{(k)},V_A^{(k)})$ represents the $k$-th sign change of $(U_A,V_A)$,
assuming a certain order.

I would like to show the (upto sign) continuity of SVD.
To do this, I want to show that 
for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for any $B$ satisfying $\|A-B\|_F < \delta$, we have
$$
\min_{k,j}\|f_k(A) - f_j(B)\|_F = \sqrt{\|U_A^{(k)}-U_B^{(j)}\|_F^2 + \|\Sigma_A-\Sigma_B\|_F^2 + \|V_A^{(k)}-V_B^{(j)}\|_F^2} < \epsilon.
$$

What I can show is that if $A$ and $B$ have the same singular vectors, i.e., $U_A = U_B$ and $V_A = V_B$, the continuity follows immediately, as $\min_{k,j}\|f_k(A) - f_j(B)\|_F = \|A-B\|_F$. 
However, not sure how to proceed when $U_A\ne U_B$ and $V_A\ne V_B$.

Any comments/suggestions/answers would be very appreciated.

Comment: Since the SVD is not unique, your function $f$ is not defined. What you could try to show instead is that if $A$ has an (not the!) SVD $A = U\Sigma V$ and $\epsilon > 0$, then there is $\delta>0$ such that each $A'$ with $\|A'-A\|<\delta$ has an SVD $A' = U'\Sigma'V'$ such that $\|U-U'\| + \|\Sigma-\Sigma'\| + \|V-V'\|<\epsilon$. In the case where the singular values of $A$ are distinct, this is true.

Comment: One try to show that as a set-valued map $f$ is continuous in some set-distance. Or just that $C=U_A^TBV_A$ is close to a diagonal matrix and that then there has to exist an SVD of $C$ with $U_C,V_C$ close to the identity.

Comment: @amsmath I modified the problem accordingly. I think what you suggests is more concise than mine. But I think they are eventually equivalent.

Comment: Since $U$ and $V$ for $tA$ and $A$ are the same if $t>0$, it is clearly not continuous at $0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Lol, true. Although the singular values are.

Comment: In fact, it cannot be continuous at any $A$ with a singular value of multiplicity larger than one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Agreed. It is even unclear to claim SVD of zero in this context. Let's assume $A$ is not zero.

Comment: @amsmath I see. Because we have infinitely many choices of constructing multiple singular vectors corresponding to the multiplicity larger than one. Then, in general, SVD is not continuous. Am I right? Can we then find the conditions under when SVD is continuous?

Comment: No. Actually, writing that "SVD is continuous" does not make sense because it's not a function and you never can make it a function, even for distinct singular value matrices.

Comment: @amsmath Thank you so much! If you could wrap your comments as an answer, I will choose your answer to credit your effort.